# Talend - IOException: com.sforce.sw.ConnectionException: Failed to get next element

Tags: data, talend

I have been using Talend for about two years to load data into Salesforce from files and have not had an issue.  All of a sudden, over the weekend it has stopped working with about 20 of my standard loads (to different orgs).

Initially I got this error

> "Exception in component tSalesforceOutputBulkExec_1_tSalesforceBulkExec (CustomerLoadSourcesNoEmail)
> org.talend.components.api.exception.ComponentException: UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION"

I tried to just re-connect with a basic connection element and got this

> "IOException: com.sforce.sw.ConnectionException: Failed to get next element"
>
> [image: Error Message]

I tried to use meta data to connect

> "IOException: com.sforce.sw.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to"
>
> [image]

I assumed the issue was Talend or Java update so I have tried everything from rolling back java, reinstalling from scratch to installing on another fresh computer.

Current setup is:

- Windows 10
- Talend 7.01.20180411_1414
- jdk1.8.0_171

So I am starting to get the feeling it might actually to do with a Salesforce release and not Talend or Java problem.

I noticed this old article with the same error
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yx5IAA

Anyone seeing anything like this recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Endpoint URL needs to be https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0 due to recent changes in salesforce.

Comment: Wow, I just lost a day of my life.  I tried a bunch of end points, why does only 39 work?

Comment: Ok not one that works, actually just need to change the default from talend from www to login.  I get it.  Wow, the error message could be clearer :)